# Is it ever necessary to declare a function inside main?

Tags: c++, function

I have a somewhat large program that uses a class A and some functions of the class and some global functions outside the class. Then I have multiple objects of the class, that I wish to manipulate simultaneously using another function. I believe (at least have been always advised) that its best to declare functions outside main.

But if I go onto declare outside main, there doesnt seem a decent way I can call my objects, as their scope is limited to main only and I do not want to pass every object as a different parameter because that would be complicating things up. I believe if I just put up my function inside main, I wont get these problems.

Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Here is an outline of code if my question isn't clear:

```
class A
{
  void A1();
  void A2();
  void A3();
} //class functions that modify class objects

void A4(); //global function(cant call apple elegantly if placed here)

int main() {
  A apple;
  A banana; //class ojects
  A4(); //gotta modify objects apple and banana by calling A1,A2,A3
        // on them depending on the user input
  return 0;
}
```

Also, In such cases, if its better to just declare the function inside main, then just let me know. I just want to know how to implement best method rather than anything redundant :)

Comment: Please reformat, an extra line or ten won't hurt you. This text is cramped too tightly.

Comment: @olevegard, Sorry. I thought it hurts eyes to scroll through text, now i realise it was dumb.

Comment: I really don't understand your question, so this might be completely off but: you know functions can take arguments, right?

Comment: @Mat, of course, this was just meant to give an idea of what I m trying to do rather than actual piece of code (which is over 400 lines and might not be a good idea to get into that) :)

Comment: Then I don't understand your question at all. Why would you even consider declaring a function inside main? Why aren't you passing whatever needs to be modified as an argument to the function?

Comment: @Mat . I want to modify 3 class objects, so that would be just 3 extra arguments everytime i call the function(which is going to be recursive in particular). I dont really see why not i just call it in main . What does it hurt to do that?

Comment: Pass a vector or some other container if you need to. Are you going to stuff your whole program into main just to avoid passing variables around? That's exactly like putting all your variables at global scope - very poor programming practice, sign of bad design.

Comment: @Mat, Yeah. I know its poor , which is why I wish to refrain from it and posted here. Not whole program, just a particular function which is meant to handle user input, rest of my function is sorted neatly enough. I started c++ a week back and I want to refrain from bad design practices :) But okay, its only 3 additional arguments, shouldnt hurt that bad to pass them I hope.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it ever necessary to declare a function inside main?

No. And in C++11, lambda would beat any other local function.

> I want to modify 3 class objects, so that would be just 3 extra arguments everytime i call the function(which is going to be recursive in particular). I dont really see why not i just call it in main . What does it hurt to do that?

You are making a function relying on global variable or variable captured into function. Your function `A4()` wants to modify any variable, just pass it in as variable and call `A4()` multiple times to manipulate N times.

```
void A4(A& a); // A4 can operate on any objects of A type

int main() {
  A apple;
  A banana; //class objects

  A4(apple);  // A4 can operate on any objects of A type
  A4(banana);
  A4(....);   
}
```

Comment: I finished implementing this and it works well. What if I made A4 a class function instead. In that case i will have to call it using one object. But i want to simultanouesly manipulate different objects, I was wondering how can i do that?

Comment: you mean make `A4()` static function of class `A`?

Comment: Oh okay, I can call it using any one object with all the objects as arguments. I suppose its not a bad thing to do?

Comment: It depends on the context and in C++ write standalone function is also not bad thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

You could make apple and banana global, that way A4 will be able to access them.

```
class A
{
public:
    void A1();
    void A2();
    void A3();
} //class functions that modify class objects


A apple;
A banana; //class ojects

void A4(); //global function

int main() {

    A4(); //gotta modify objects. But want to place this function outside main
    return 0;
}

void A4()
{
    // do some stuff with apple and banana
}
```

But i would prefer to avoid globals and just let A4 take the object by reference that should be manipulated/ or whatever you want to do with it.

like:

```
void A4(A& a)
{
    // do some stuff with a
}
```

Comment: Cool enough . I will follow the latter. Dont want to bring in globals :)

Answer (score 0):

This is an OOP design issue.

If all classes should have the same method. You should make a superclass, having that method. And then inherit from that class making the other class. In that way all the classes have that one method in common and you only have to write the implementation once ;-)

Indeed, having a global method is ugly and against OOP principles. Although one could argue the OOP methods as well.

Comment: I suppose my question isnt clear. There is only one class. My question is about how to efficiently manipulate objects by not declaring my function A4 inside main? I have to manipulate 3 objects in particular. No better way than 3 arguments everytime when i can just reference them directly in main?

Comment: An argument is kind of a reference as well; If you want to manipulate an object with (any) method you have to give a reference to that object to the method. 

It is not a good practice to make global methods (unless you are coding in C) - and even then you would 'hide' them in separate header files.

You will have to let A4 take an object of that class as an argument

    A4(someClass objectreference);

Comment: If your objects are globally defined you can drop the arguments and just use

A4() and hard code that that method has to modify object apple and banana, however this is not a good programming practice and will give you trouble when you or other co-workers change the name of apple in strawberry after a review. Imagine this will give tremendous trouble when working in large files.

Answer (score 0):

you can use A4() as an ordinary function and make the members of class A accessible by A4() by specifying it as a friend function of class A

```
    class A{

     friend void A4 ( A & );

     public:
           void A1(){...}

           void A2(){...}

    };

    void A4 ( A& );

    void A4(A &apple)
    {
      apple.A1();
      apple.A2();
      ....
    }

    int main()
    {
       A apple;

       A4(apple);

       return 0;
     }
```

please note that the statement in class A

```
    friend void A4(A &);
```

is just an access specification not the declaration of function A4